fill_between cmap in subplots
The cmap keyword in matplotlib's function fill_between does nothing and I've want to use the workaround suggested in this answer:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = x * (10 - x) / 25

polygon = plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, lw=0, color='none')
xlim = plt.xlim()
ylim = plt.ylim()
verts = np.vstack([p.vertices for p in polygon.get_paths()])
gradient = plt.imshow(np.linspace(0, 1, 256).reshape(1, -1), cmap='turbo', aspect='auto',
                      extent=[verts[:, 0].min(), verts[:, 0].max(), verts[:, 1].min(), verts[:, 1].max()])
gradient.set_clip_path(polygon.get_paths()[0], transform=plt.gca().transData)
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.ylim(ylim)
plt.show()


However, I can't get it to work inside a subplot. If I modify the code above I get two empty subplots.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = x * (10 - x) / 25

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)

polygon = axs[0].fill_between(x, y1, y2, lw=0, color='none')
xlim = axs[0].get_xlim()
ylim = axs[0].get_ylim()
verts = np.vstack([p.vertices for p in polygon.get_paths()])
gradient = axs[0].imshow(np.linspace(0, 1, 256).reshape(1, -1), cmap='turbo', aspect='auto',
                      extent=[verts[:, 0].min(), verts[:, 0].max(), verts[:, 1].min(), verts[:, 1].max()])
gradient.set_clip_path(polygon.get_paths()[0], transform=plt.gca().transData)
axs[0].set_xlim(xlim)
axs[0].set_ylim(ylim)
plt.show()


How should I modify the code so that it works with subplots?

Not sure why you're using two subplots, but changing plt.fill_between ---> axs[0].fill_between and plt.gca().transData ---> axs[0].transData produces the desired result on the first subplot. In summary, avoid mixing the pyplot and object-oriented interfaces.
